# Advice as to why gaining points in a PHP game does not work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm now creating a text based mafia game. No, not another one of them. I'm just making one for the purpose of practicing PHP. I've already learned a lot, but I have encountered a problem which I can't find an answer to on the internet due to the fact that I don't know what to search for, and thus I require your help.

The function I'm making is some sort of a theft function. You can select an option and you will then have a set chance depending on your rank of being successful. If you are successful you will gain "XP" (experience points). I will add money and a timer so you can not just redo it, but that's not the problem.

Let's say you are the rank "Civilian", then you will gain XP if you make it, which works, and if you pass 100 XP your rank will change to "Wannabe". Now, if you are a wannabe it is going to be the same, though this time you will have to hit 250 XP to rank up. Now the code just won't work.

I have obviously created the MySQL connection and the database selection, and it is working. I just didn't see the point in including this in the code shared here.

```
$id  = $row['id'];
$rank   = $row['rank'];
$xp     = $row['xp'];
$theft  = $_POST['option'];
$chance = rand(1,100);

if ($theft == 1) {

    if ($rank == 'Civilian') {

    if ($chance > '60') {
       echo "You made it.";
       mysql_query("UPDATE users SET xp = xp + 50 WHERE id=$id");

    if ($xp > '100') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rank = 'Wannabe' WHERE id=$id");
        }

    } else {
        echo 'You did not make it';
    }
}

} else if ($rank == 'Wannabe') {

if ($chance > '50') {
    echo "You made it.";
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET xp = xp + 50 WHERE id=$id");

    if ($xp > '250') {
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rank = 'Thief' WHERE id=$id");
    }

} else {
        echo 'You did not make it';
    }
}
```

I'm fully aware that this might not be the best way to program this, though this is probably the best I can do right now. What is it that does not work in my code? Is there anyway I can make it work? And are there better solutions?

I am really thankful for any reply. Even if it's just some sort of a lead so I can progress.

**Edit:** These are just the first two ranks for the first option in the form. You have four different crimes you can do, and that is `$theft == 1`. There are three more. There are also about 5 ranks. So I think this is bad coding. I just don't know how I can do it better.

Comment: PHP for games. Interesting.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the xp being added to the database?

Comment: You're comparing against the $chance variable which is a result of rand(). rand() returns an int whereas you're comparing against strings: `$chance > '50'` should be `$chance > 50`. In general it seems like you're relying too much on PHP's type juggling.

Comment: @MikeB True, but largely a matter of coding style, given PHP's typing model, as it will still behave as expected: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zkCx6I

Comment: I know you are just learning, but you really should start learning to use object oriented PHP.  It is made exactly for this sort of thing.  You also you learn to work with MySQL using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Finally, when working with the database, make sure you are actually checking the results of your queries,  and handling errors.  It will make debugging your code 1000x easier.

Comment: @Jason When you hit the rank wannabe you won't be able to clear the $chance test anymore. You won't gain xp, nor rank up. Though, this works whenn your rank is Civilian.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one problem I see right off the bat:

You are reading in the current XP value:

```
$xp = $row['xp'];
```

Then, on success, updating the DB value:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET xp = xp + 50 WHERE id=$id");
```

But you are then testing the XP value for progression *using the pre-success value*

```
if ($xp > '100')...
```

So you are not taking into account the new 50 points...

On success, make your $xp = $xp + 50

Then set the database value to that.

Also, I agree 100% with @PiX06 -- check out `switch` statements, they are your friend here! Also, think about putting all the XP update stuff in a separate function and calling it when necessary, since that logic is just being repeated over and over. Anytime you see you are typing out the same code multiple times, it is time to look for ways to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't directly answer your question but consider using a switch statement for your logic above. It will make it less messy when you add other ranks.

For example:

```
<?php
$rank = "civillian";

switch ($rank){
    case "wannabe":
        dostuff();
        break;
    case "civillian":
        doOtherStuff();
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I had forgotten something simple as that. But I still don't know why my code won't work. Though, if I switch it out with case, it might just work.